# Modulus on both sides of an equation

Tags: coordinate-systems

I've got a doubt while solving one of my problems on coordinate geometry. It's kinda conceptual doubt.
I was just wondering what to do if I'm rendered with this situation:

> | a - b | = | c - d |

The modulus comes from solving for areas of polygons in coordinate geometry. Say I've got variables on both sides, what do I do next?

Comment: It depends on what you want to get. What do you want to get? What is a given?

Comment: What are the unknowns ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Variables. You can take any arbitrary example. Say you're given the coordinates of vertices of triangles in variables and something additional that could help you figure out the variables, say the ratio of area of two triangles.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is loose, so will the answer.

Rewrite as

$$(a_x-b_x)^2+(a_y-b_y)^2=(c_x-d_x)^2+(c_y-d_y)^2.$$